# Bitbucket Pull Not working suddenly

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

When tried to pull the repo today, it say below error, but last several months it was working. Have tried with Bitbucket website, but no info about it. Is anyone in facing the same? Is Atalassian provided any work around for it?

```
 sudo git pull

Password for 'https://stutzen@bitbucket.org': 
remote: Repositories on team accounts can only be accessed through a team member. Using a team password is not allowed.
```

Comment: It seems the username you used (`stutzen`) is no longer a member of the team that owns the repository.

Comment: permission is available.

Comment: seems changes in Bitbucket

Answer (score 2):

This is due to changes in Bitbucket:

https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/01/14/important-changes-are-coming-to-teams/

Clearly, the date kept getting pushed back, but this has been coming for a while.

There's a bit more detail at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/team-account-changes-454361799.html .

Answer (score 0):

In the "url = " line of the .git/config file, you'll want to edit the 'USERNAME' portion as in the example below to be your new individual user id.

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/TEAM_ID/REPO_SLUG
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/TEAM_ID/REPO_SLUG
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Source: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/team-account-changes-454361799.html