# Bitbucket Using a team password is not allowed

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have add a user to a specific repository in BitBucket through "User and group access". The user can see the repository, when he logs in into his account.

When he tries to make a git clone https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/company/reposistory.git he gets since 1 Week this error:

Repositories on team accounts can only be accessed through a team member. Using a team password is not allowed.
fatal: unable to access 'https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/company/reposistory.git': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket [has changed the way team accounts work](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2014/01/14/important-changes-are-coming-to-teams/) (emphasis mine):

> Starting February 18, 2014, *Bitbucket will remove the ability for individuals to log into a team with a username/email and password*. We are taking this action so that we can bring you Atlassian ID later this year. [Atlassian ID is single sign-on](https://id.atlassian.com/about/faq) across all our OnDemand services such as Bitbucket, JIRA, HipChat and Confluence, one of the most popular feature requests on Bitbucket!

The solution is also listed on that page:

> *If you login to your team with a username and password, you will need to appoint or create an administrator for your team.* We’ve added a warning banner to your account which will walk you through this process. You will also receive an email with instructions on what to do next.

It's true that February 18, 2014 was actually quite a long time ago, but [it looks like this change may not actually have taken effect until recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396227/354577).